# How to define an entity type within entity_get_info()

Tags: 7, entities

Is it possible to define your own entity type so that a call to entity_get_info() returns your new type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. You use the hook_entity_info() hook.

https://www.drupal.org/node/1026420

Comment: You may also want to look at Entity API, which is more robust than the core entity in 7. https://www.drupal.org/project/entity